# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '}', expected ')'

Tags: python, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am new to Python and I am stuck with this error. I've double-checked my steps but am not sure what else to do. Please help me.

```
  File "/Users/d/PycharmProjects/interpretersblog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/d/PycharmProjects/interpretersblog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/d/PycharmProjects/interpretersblog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/d/PycharmProjects/interpretersblog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/d/PycharmProjects/interpretersblog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/d/PycharmProjects/interpretersblog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/d/PycharmProjects/interpretersblog/Flask_Blog/flaskblog.py", line 28, in register
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
  File "/Users/d/PycharmProjects/interpretersblog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 148, in render_template
    ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "/Users/d/PycharmProjects/interpretersblog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1068, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/Users/d/PycharmProjects/interpretersblog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 997, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
  File "/Users/d/PycharmProjects/interpretersblog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 958, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/Users/d/PycharmProjects/interpretersblog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 137, in load
    code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
  File "/Users/d/PycharmProjects/interpretersblog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 757, in compile
    self.handle_exception(source=source_hint)
  File "/Users/d/PycharmProjects/interpretersblog/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 925, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "/Users/d/PycharmProjects/interpretersblog/Flask_Blog/templates/register.html", line 13, in template
    {{ form.email.label (class="form-control-label"}}
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '}', expected ')'
```

Here is the forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)])

    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])

    password = PasswordField('Password',
                             validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])

    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])

    password = PasswordField('Password',
                             validators=[DataRequired()])

    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')

    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

And register.html:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today!</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.username.label (class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.username.label (class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.email.label (class="form-control-label"}}
                    {{ form.email.label (class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.password.label (class="form-control-label"}}
                    {{ form.password.label (class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.confirm_password.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.confirm_password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">
            Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Sign In</a>
        </small>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: `{{ form.email.label (class="form-control-label"}}` is missing a `)` before the final `}}` I see the same typo on the `form.password.label` line as well. If you carefully read the error message, that's exactly what it is telling you and even indicates the offending line.

Comment: Fixed, also did password but now I am getting this:

Comment: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'else'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'.

Comment: Was `else` supposed to be `if`?

Comment: Ok. No need for else, elseif. For those who will be looking for a solution, I will post my final edits. Thank you so much Cory.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today!</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.username.label (class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.email.label (class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.password.label (class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.confirm_password.label (class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.confirm_password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">
            Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Sign In</a>
        </small>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

```html
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])

    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])

    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])

    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):

    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])

    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember me ')

    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).